# Unique constraint on multiple columns when any columns are not null

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I am trying to add a unique constraint on 2 columns that allows multiple `(null, null)`, but doesn't allow multiple `("a", null)`. I wrote the following SQL statement but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'

SQL statement:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ] 
ON [dbo].[MyTable] ([Column_A], [Column_B])
WHERE [Column_A] IS NOT NULL OR [Column_B] IS NOT NULL
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY];
```

However in

```
 WHERE [Column_A] IS NOT NULL OR [Column_B] IS NOT NULL
```

when I replace `OR` with `AND`, there is no syntax error anymore. But what I want is `OR` logic, not `AND` because using `AND` allows multiple `("a", null)` entries.

So why is there an incorrect syntax error using `OR`? Thanks.

Comment: you can create a view with the desired Where clause then create a unique index on that to enforce this. the filtered index grammar only allows `<filter_predicate> ::=   <conjunct> [ AND <conjunct> ]`

Comment: Thanks. I have written an answer based on your comment. @Martin Smith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit clunky, but if the point is to enforce uniqueness (except for NULL/NULL) and you're happy having two indexes, you can do it via putting the NOT NULL filters on separate indexes e.g.,

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
[UQ_A] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Column_A],
    [Column_B]
)
WHERE [Column_A] IS NOT NULL
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
[UQ_B] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Column_A],
    [Column_B]
)
WHERE [Column_B] IS NOT NULL
GO
```

While it's not necessary for the uniqueness check, you may want to change the order of the fields in the second index to potentially gain additional advantages of the index (depending on how these fields are used in your application - it may be better swapping them in the first index),  e.g.,

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
[UQ_B] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Column_B],
    [Column_A] 
)
WHERE [Column_B] IS NOT NULL
GO
```

Comment: It has the advantage of keeping the constraints/etc within the table itself. It makes it easier when other coders need to use it, or when you come back to it in 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

According to Martin Smith's comment, I think I can implement it by:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TableAView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT
[ColumnA] = [ColumnA],
[ColumnB] = [ColumnB]
FROM [dbo].[TableA]
WHERE [ColumnA] IS NOT NULL OR [ColumnB] IS NOT NULL;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
[UQ] ON [dbo].[TableAView]
(
    [ColumnA],
    [ColumnB]
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```